# OutOfMemoryError starting volley RequestQueue

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-volley

I'm using fragments and volley for my app but when I try to initialize the volley RequestQueue my app crashes and throws an OutOfMemoryError, it is trying to initialize 1.8 GB of data into memory

```
    05-12 18:00:51.947  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker W/dalvikvm﹕ 1802465107 byte    allocation exceeds the 67108864 byte maximum heap size
    05-12 18:00:51.947  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1802465107-byte allocation
    05-12 18:00:51.981  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 330K, 6% free 8660K/9207K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 1802465107-byte allocation.
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ "Thread-1108" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41718598 self=0x51363d10
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=10781 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1362874264
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ | schedstat=( 43264540 285215383 80 ) utm=4 stm=0 core=1
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:~316)
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:548)
    05-12 18:00:51.982  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
    05-12 18:00:51.983  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
    05-12 18:00:51.983  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
    05-12 18:00:51.983  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 05-12 18:00:51.984 10765:0x2a1d D/dalvikvm ]
threadid=11: exiting
    05-12 18:00:51.984  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e51908)
    05-12 18:00:51.986  10765-10781/com.sellcom.tracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1108
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:548)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
        at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
```

I reduced my fragment implementation to show where the crash occurs:

```
public class FragmentWeather extends Fragment{

RequestQueue queue;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
}
```

}

The error is caused by this sentence:

```
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
```

Does anybody knows why is this happening? Any time I tried to create a new request queue the error is thrown.

Comment: Something tries to allocate 1.8GB of memory... My suggestion would be to strip down the code to the minimal number of lines that still produces the problem. Either you find the problem on the way, or the question will be easier to answer.

Comment: @Nicolas78 I tried that already, but the problem is not the code length, wether I have the empty class or the full code if I try to execute the line: 

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()); the app throws that error

Comment: well but if you've tried it and it didn't help, I'd suggest you post the reduced version you already created so people don't have to look at code that you already found out doesn't matter to the problem

Comment: Solved it! Something went crazy inside my phone, just restarted it and the code worked again.

Comment: lol that's how it is sometimes :)

Comment: I encounter this too, clearing app data fixes it but how do I prevent it

Comment: @CQM Please edit the question to explain why this is not just a one-off error, and what you know (or what you don't know) about when it occurs. That will help get it reopened.

Comment: @Veedrac there are other questions here like this already where Volley throws this exact error attempting to allocate a gigabyte+ of memory, some are related to Volley's diskbasedcache initialization and starting Volley in the application class. This question was just wrong closed but I don't have a fixed for this particular one

Comment: @CQM I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I asked you to edit the question to be more clear about the error so it can be reopened so you can get an answer.

Comment: I get this error a lot when using Genymotion to test my app.  I have to go to Settings > apps > and clear my app's cache to solve it.

Comment: @Nicolas78 can you vote to reopen this question?

Comment: @CarlosJimenez can you vote to reopen this question?

Comment: @Veedrac can you vote to reopen this question?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky can you vote to reopen this question?